# Why HTML use class or id attributes and not . or # attributes?

Tags: html

I was wondering why HTML / HTML5 is using class and id attributes like:

```
<div class="my_class" id="my_id"></div>
```

and not:

```
<div .my_class #my_id></div>
```

like in css.

It's way shorter, way easier and it's understandable by everyone.

There should be a good reason but I can't find it.

Comment: So create a parser that takes that format and generates correct HTML.

Comment: I do not understand why this is down voted. Its clear, short and to the point. Maybe not a good idea, but surly we don't rate with personal opinion?

Comment: Thanks a lot Persijn. People on Stackoverflow can be rude sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a few reason:

Although CSS and HTML get used with each other, it's a different language. HTML was build before CSS, because of this they don't match. Yes it could be redone in a newer HTML version but this would mean that developers need to relearn a bit of code and it would not be backwards compatible. Many extension libraries relay on this something="this", even JavaScript does.

Second:

If you add multiple classes to one element you would need to do something like: .class1 .class2 .

Also it doesn't take much effort by doing this and if it would someone could build a JavaScript library or something to convert .myclassx to class="myclassx"

It is just some that has been so since the start of HTML and will most likely not change ever.